# 403 error when trying to search twitter, Processing, Twitter4j, controlP5

Tags: twitter, processing, twitter4j

When executing a twitter query i get a 403 error, the error message is below, however my other queries work perfectly and are executed prior to this one, can anyone spot what may be wrong here:

> TWITTER EXCEPTION: TwitterException{exceptionCode=[f3acd3ed-00581fa3], statusCode=403, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.5-SNAPSHOT(build: d372a51b9b419cbd73d416474f4a855f3e889507)}

this occurs when i execute a search from my app, im not overdoing the limits as i can execute my other searches perfectly its just this one, any help would be appreciated, the code is listed below. im using a combination of Twitter4j and Processing with controlP5 to handle the input like the search.

```
void setup(){
...
             cp5.addTextfield("SEARCH")
             .setPosition(30,20)
             .setSize(100,20)
             .setFocus(true)
             .setColor(color(255,0,0))
             .setGroup(g2)
             ;
}

      public void SEARCH(String theText) {
        qm.srch = true;
        qm.theText = theText;
        qm.userSearch();
        qm.srch = false;
        // automatically receives results from controller input
        println("a textfield event for controller 'input' : "+theText);
      }

  void userSearch() {
    try {
      if (srch) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb9 = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb9.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        cb9.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx");
        cb9.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        cb9.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        println("Connected");
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb9.build()).getInstance();
        Query srchh = new Query(theText2);

        srchh.setRpp(5);
        QueryResult srchhRes = twitter.search(srchh);
        ArrayList srchhTwe = (ArrayList) srchhRes.getTweets();
        for (int i = 0; i < srchhTwe.size(); i++) {

          Tweet t = (Tweet) srchhTwe.get(i);
          String user = t.getFromUser();
          GeoLocation l = t.getGeoLocation();
          String locNam = t.getLocation();
          String msg = t.getText();
          wholeTweetsL.add(msg);
          println("\nMessage: " + msg);
          println("\nLocation: " + locNam);
        }
      }
    }
    catch(TwitterException e) {
      println("TWITTER EXCEPTION: " + e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From twitter at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

403 Forbidden   The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.

Comment: yeah, iv read what the error is, however other queries in the same class work and search fine, that is my issue.